# python pycrypto: module' object has no attribute 'importKey'

Tags: python, pycrypto

I'm currently working with pycrypto and I want to import public key,but it can not work and raise some error: **'module' object has no attribute 'importKey''**
I also use pycrypto in my other script,it works well,so I can not understand why this can not work.
my code that can't work is as following:

```
    from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
    .............
    .............
    def task_name(task):
        username = task['user']
        taskintid = task['taskintid']
        data = '%s,%s' % (str(username), str(taskintid))
        user_id = task.get('op_user_id', '')
        db = get_db()

        ssh_key = db.ssh_key.find_one({'user_id': user_id})
        if ssh_key:
            try:
                public_key = RSA.importKey(ssh_key.get('ssh_key', ''))
                data = public_key.encrypt(data, 32)[0].encode('hex')
            except Exception, e:
                print e

    return "task-%s-%s" % (data, task['repeat_num'])
```

also, my python version is **2.6.5**
=======================================
sorry,I forgot it, the pycrypto version is **2.0.1**
because I have installed many packages,so I can not upgrage my pycrypto version

Comment: my script seems same to the doc, the difference is it get the key from file but I get the key from db

Comment: It is actually your version that is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for exporting and importing RSA keys was implemented in version 2.2 listed in the [changelog](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/blob/62247ca754657b6ee8370d8fd62c58b8b881f396/ChangeLog)  so unless you can upgrade you are out of luck.

Comment: is there other module can replace the pycrypto?

Comment: why can't you upgrade?

Comment: because there are too many other packages and if I upgrade pycrypto,it will upgrade its dependency,so other module can not work.but still thank you for your answer ,you are right.

Comment: If you use virtualenv, you can install the latest PyCrypto just for your application.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by `pip install pycryptodome`